# A calculator in C++

Tags: c++, console, io

I want to make my calculator code shorter.

Here is my code:

```
extern "C"
{
    int printf(const char *format, ...);
    extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);
    double pow(double x, double y);
}

int main()
{
    do
    {
        double num1;
        double a, b = 1;
        char ch1;
        float r;
        scanf("%lf", &num1);
        printf("\ta - Factorial\n\tb - Continue\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ch1);
        switch (ch1)
        {
            case 'a':
                r = b;
                for (a = 1; a <= num1; a++)
                {
                    b = b * a;
                }
                if (b < 500000001 & num1 > 0)
                {
                    printf("%f\n", b);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (b > 500000000)
                    {
                        printf("Number is Big\n");
                    }
                    if (num1 < 1)
                    {
                        printf("Number is Small\n");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 'b':
                double num2;
                char ch2;
                scanf("%lf", &num2);
                printf("\ta - Add\n\tb - Substract\n\tc - Multiply\n\td - Divide\n\te - Power\n\tf - Radical\n");
                scanf(" %c", &ch2);
                switch (ch2)
                {
                    case 'a':
                        r = num1 + num2;
                        if (num1 + num2 < 500000001 & num1 + num2 > -500000001 & num1 - num2 < 500000001 & num2 - num1 < 500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf + %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else if (num1 + num2 > 500000000)
                        {
                            printf("Number is Big\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        r = num1 - num2;
                        if (num1 + num2 < 500000001 & num1 + num2 > -500000001 & num1 - num2 < 500000001 & num2 - num1 < 500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf - %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else if (num1 + num2 > 500000000)
                        {
                            printf("Number is Big\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                        r = num1 * num2;
                        if (num1 * num2 < 500000001 & num1 * num2 > -500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf * %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (num1 * num2 > 500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Big\n");
                            }
                            if (num1 * num2 < -500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Small\n");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                        r = num1 / num2;
                        if (num1 * num2 < 500000001 & num1 * num2 > -500000001 && num2 > 0 | num1 == 0 & num2 != 0)
                        {
                            printf("%lf / %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (num1 * num2 > 500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Big\n");
                            }
                            if (num1 * num2 < -500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Small\n");
                            }
                            if (num1 > 0 & num2 == 0 | num1 == 0 & num2 == 0)
                            {
                                printf("Undefined\n");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'e':
                        r = pow(num1, num2);
                        if (pow(num1, num2) < 500000001 & pow(num1, num2) > -500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf ^ %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pow(num1, num2) > 500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Big\n");
                            }
                            if (pow(num1, num2) > -500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Small\n");
                            }
                        }
                    case 'f':
                        r = pow(num1, 1 / num2);
                        if (pow(num1, num2) < 500000001 & pow(num1, num2) > -500000001)
                        {
                            printf("%lf √ %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pow(num1, num2) > 500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Big\n");
                            }
                            if (pow(num1, num2) > -500000000)
                            {
                                printf("Number is Small\n");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("Invalid\n");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    while (1);
}
```

Can I make this code shorter? Is it possible to do? If it is, how?

(This code may be updated in my [GitHub](https://github.com/ArianKG) account.)

Comment: We can only review the code that's here, so your requirement (2) is off-topic for Code Review.  What do you have against `#include`, anyway?  That's the standard means of accessing library functions, and much safer than declaring standard functions as you have done here.

Comment: This is not C++, it is C.

Comment: It is C++. You can test it.

Comment: While it appears that the edits don't really incorporate advice from the answer, please be aware: after receiving an answer you should not make changes to your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). See the section _What should I not do?_ on [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information

Comment: @Arian: It compiles like a C program. What about it makes it C++?

Comment: Although a C++ compiler would compile this program, nothing about it is C++,.

Comment: @MartinYork My file name is Program.cpp

Comment: @Arian Read my answer below. Lots of C code can be compiled by the C++ compiler.

Comment: @Arian This code is quite bad and poorly written. IMO, I think the you should focus more on writing cleaner code than trying to make the code short.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 8 → 7. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Questions:

> Can I make this code shorter?

Yes

> Is it possible to do?

Yes

> If it is, how?

By using functions. You can move common code to a named function.

### Notes

This is C code not C++.

Sure it compiles with a C++ compiler (so does a lot of C). C++ is a style of programming, you are not using the C++ style you are using the C style of programming.

Additionally, you are using a lot of C library functions that have C++ equivalents.

### Review

1. Split your code into functions
2. Use C++ libraries (not C)
3. Improve your user interface (ask the question then expect answers).

Comment: It is bad C++ code, avoiding all the good points of writing C++, in a bad C-like style. But it is most certainly C++ despite that. And it is indubitably not C.

Answer (score 7):

There is no better way to say this, but your code is shockingly bad. I will just provide a short summary of the things that can be improved:

- `#include` headers like everyone else does, don't forward declare standard library functions.
- Since you tagged the post C++, use C++'s `iostream` functionality; it gives you type safety.
- Split your program into several functions, and just have a small loop in `main()` that reads input and calls another function to do the processing.
- Use either `double` or `float`, don't mix them. Why is `r` a `float`?
- Don't use arbitrary numbers to check if something is "big". Just don't check the result at all, print it and let the user decide whether they think it is useful or not.
- Use `&&` instead of `&`, the latter is a bitwise AND which does not do what you want.

Comment: Pre-C++20 iostream has some often critical shortcomings compared to stdio. Still, [`<format>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) mostly solved that, and they are not really important here, imho.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a full review, but try using functions actually used in modern C++. There is no point in using `printf()` and `scanf()`, as they are just in the language for C-portability. `std::cout` and `std::cin` would be the C++ equivalents (you have to `#include <iostream>`).

Comment: *Just* for C portability? Not that that isn't important enough by itself, but iostream has some distinct advantages (and not only disadvantages) over pre-C++20 iostream.